# Error: Cannot find module 'iconv-lite'

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gruntjs

Well i am trying to run a **nodejs** script in **Jenkins**, but when i trigger the build i get this  **Error: Cannot find module 'iconv-lite'**

so to prevent this i also tried to install the module **"npm install iconv-lite  --save-dev"**
but still i face the same issue.

My job configuration consists of a shell script followed by a nodejs script.

Shell script data:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-copy --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-requirejs --save-dev
npm install grunt-connect-proxy --save-dev
npm install iconv-lite --save-dev
```

here is the console output

```
[test_js] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3463493438343490126.sh
+ npm install grunt-connect-proxy --save-dev
grunt-connect-proxy@0.2.0 node_modules/grunt-connect-proxy
├── lodash@0.9.2
└── http-proxy@1.11.3 (eventemitter3@1.2.0, requires-port@0.0.1)
+ npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
grunt-contrib-watch@1.0.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch
├── async@1.5.2
├── gaze@1.0.0 (globule@0.2.0)
├── lodash@3.10.1
└── tiny-lr@0.2.1 (parseurl@1.3.1, livereload-js@2.2.2, qs@5.1.0, debug@2.2.0, faye-websocket@0.10.0, body-parser@1.14.2)
+ npm install grunt-contrib-copy --save-dev
grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy
├── file-sync-cmp@0.1.1
└── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@2.2.1, supports-color@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1, has-ansi@2.0.0)
+ npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
grunt-contrib-uglify@1.0.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify
├── uri-path@1.0.0
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.1, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1)
├── uglify-js@2.6.2 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, source-map@0.5.6, yargs@3.10.0)
├── maxmin@1.1.0 (figures@1.7.0, gzip-size@1.0.0, pretty-bytes@1.0.4)
└── lodash@4.13.1
+ npm install grunt-contrib-requirejs --save-dev
grunt-contrib-requirejs@1.0.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-requirejs
└── requirejs@2.2.0
+ npm install iconv-lite --save-dev
iconv-lite@0.4.13 node_modules/iconv-lite
[test_js] $ /usr/local/bin/node /tmp/hudson7464326776362659565.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'iconv-lite'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/hudson402761881726281197.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
Build step 'Execute NodeJS script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

In most of such questions, i found solution is to use "npm install module-name",
i have tried installing on my linux machine and also by giving it in shell script of job configuration but in this case it isn't working.

Well when i try to install it globally using **"npm install module_name -g --save-dev"**

```
# npm install grunt-connect-proxy -g --save-dev
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt requires grunt-    cli@'~1.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.8
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-connect-proxy" "-g" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.0.0
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-connect-proxy@0.2.0 wants grunt@~0.4.1

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jenkins/npm-debug.log
```

and the grunt-version is

```
# grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.8
grunt v0.4.5
```

what could be the possible reason?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this file you're trying to call (`/tmp/hudson7464326776362659565.js`) - is it on the root or is it in a subfolder of your project?

Comment: @theaccordance : i am not trying to call it but it is called automatically from jenkins, i tried to look at this file (/tmp/hudson7464326776362659565.js) and didnot find it. It specifies /tmp directory, a temporary file created during execution of the job and destroyed after execution

Comment: could anyone help me?

Comment: I can't provide much help unless you can stop jenkins from destroying these temporary files